# Printing poster from inDesign file

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, cs6, print-production

I've inherited an InDesign file and I'm new to the software. I need to send an exported PDF to print a 30"x40" poster from this InDesign file. The InDesign file was designed as a simple flyer, at 8.5"x11".

How do I upscale this file so I can export it as a PDF to print this poster? Or can I use the file as is and simply export the PDF, would that produce a high enough quality file?

Any help for me is appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing the nature of the InDesign content, this is difficult to answer. If there are raster images placed in the InDesign file, you may not simply be able to enlarge things.

Comment: Has the indesign file got accompanying images that are linked, do you have all the fonts - all that kind of thing is important.

Answer (score 2):

- Create a new document that is 30" x 40"
- Open the original document
- Select everything on the page (<kbd>Ctl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and copy (<kbd>Ctl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
- Switch to the new document and paste (<kbd>Ctl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). Everything will be selected at this point, and the artwork will be centered on the new page. Don't click anywhere on the document or you'll deselect all of some of the objects.
- Hold <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> on Mac), and drag one corner until the artwork fills the new page.
- Deselect, then adjust individual elements as needed.

If the artwork contains images, check their effective ppi by selecting them and checking the value returned in the Info panel. If any are below 150 ppi, you might want to consider replacing them with higher-resolution versions. Otherwise, you'll be good to go.